# using jqBarGraph in my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hi i need to have a graph in my html page after searching for long time i came to know that using jqBarGraph plug-in it is easy to create the graph ,Below given is the code for my page :

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jqBarGraph.js"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">

 arrayOfData = new Array(
     [10.3,'Jan','#f3f3f3'],
     [15.2,'Feb','#f4f4f4'],
     [13.1,'Mar','#cccccc'],
     [16.3,'Apr','#333333'],
     [14.5,'May','#666666']
);
   $('#divForGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData });

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="divForGraph" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black;">
   aksdljfkladsjf;oajsdfkmlmnmnk;asdf
   </div>
   </body>
   </html>
```

what is the mistake i've done in this code and correct me in getting the graph in this page asap....thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to wait until the Div is loaded to manipulate the div contents using jQuery / jqgraph.

Place your script after the div is loaded.

Also the CSS style file is missing, I added that.

The below fixed code works.

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jqBarGraph.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/styles.css" type="text/css" />
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="divForGraph" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black;">
   </div>
   <script type="text/javascript">

 arrayOfData = new Array(
     [10.3,'Jan','#f3f3f3'],
     [15.2,'Feb','#f4f4f4'],
     [13.1,'Mar','#cccccc'],
     [16.3,'Apr','#333333'],
     [14.5,'May','#666666']
);
   $('#divForGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData });

   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

There is another fix fir this without moving your scripts to the bottom of the page. Alternatively, you can also use jQuery's `$(document).ready()` to wait until the document is loaded and then run your jqBar script!

```
<html>
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/jqBarGraph.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.workshop.rs/jqbargraph/styles.css" type="text/css" />

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#divForGraph').jqBarGraph({ data: arrayOfData });

});
 arrayOfData = new Array(
     [10.3,'Jan','#f3f3f3'],
     [15.2,'Feb','#f4f4f4'],
     [13.1,'Mar','#cccccc'],
     [16.3,'Apr','#333333'],
     [14.5,'May','#666666']
);

   </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <div id="divForGraph" style="width:100%; height:100%; border:1px solid black;">
   </div>

   </body>
   </html>
```